# Метод close() и системные ресурсы

Tags: java, потоки-данных, поток-ввода, выделение-памяти

У потоков есть метод **close()**. Когда я читаю для чего нужен этот метод я встречаюсь с такой формулировкой: "для освобождения системных ресурсов".

**Вопрос**: а что такое эти "системные ресурсы"? Это память из "кучи"? Если да, то почему следующий код выдает выдаёт не **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError**, а **java.io.FileNotFoundException**

```
import java.io.*;

class Main{
        public static void main(String[] args)
                throws IOException {

                FileInputStream qq;

                while(true){
                        qq = new FileInputStream("qwer.txt");
                }

        }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: qwer.txt (Too many open files)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111)
        at Main.main(Main3.java:10)
```

Comment: У операционной системы есть разные ограничения. Например, кол-во одновременных файлов. Если их только открывать, а не закрывать, то скоро система скажет айайай. Вот эти файлы и есть разновидность системных ресурсов

Comment: Добавлю лишь, что метод close входит в интерфейс closebale, что позволяет использовать try-with-resources, что позволяет быть уверенным в том, что метод close будет гарантированно вызван, а также сокращает количество необходимого/стандартного/boilreplate кода.